# React-Native and Redux: How to reuse reducer to handle multiple component

Tags: react-native, redux, state, state-management

I am not sure whether I understood redux and react native. I am currently writing an app required to fetch data from server. I have one login reducer, two different function to fetch a set of different data from server and loading to two different list.

A login component will have one reducer which have different states whereas other list will have their own reducer which handle their states that do begin, loading, end etc quite similar between the two.

Is it the way it work. or can I have the same reducer that serves two components e.g the lists mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux has a "Single source of truth", in other words, it has a single `store`. No matter how many reducers you make, they are ultimately combined together using `combineReducers` method provided by redux, and all reducers are executed against every `action` in your app.

It is just up to you to capture that action (using switch case over `action type`) in whichever reducer you like and update your redux store accordingly.

Subsequently, since there is a state change, your components re-render and that's when you get the data from the store and update your component.

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Thank for explanation. Sometime confusing and not sure really need for some components.

Comment: It's fairly easy to understand if you understand the behavior of `actions` and `reducers`. Redux is really well documented. I suggest you read the documentation and understand as much as possible.